# Squarespace Custom CSS - How can I bring an image in front of default blocks?

Tags: html, css, squarespace

I'm helping a friend who's making a website with Squarespace, and I'm trying to add a picture of her in front of her "About" page; the problem I'm having is that I can't get the picture to sit on top of the Squarespace content blocks. Anyone know if there's a way for me to override the default stuff?

I've already tried applying `z-index` and `position:relative` with a `<span>` tag, and that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: The question is really too theoretical without a demo of the situation.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is probably not the way to do it on Squarespace. Since Squarespace is a CMS you'll want to leverage as much of the built-in tools as possible before moving into the Custom CSS.

I've never heard of the request to place an image **above** other content. Typically you're placing the image underneath. Regardless, a great way to do images in front other images is by using Squarespace's built in **Gallery Block** set to **Grid** mode. This would give you one block with two images in the same container which you could then add styling to customize. Link: https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544027-Using-the-Grid-Gallery-Block